# instance variable inside edit method for webform (Rails)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails (version 4) question: I have a table called "sections" and I generate a controller called Sections like this:
`rails generate controller Sections index show edit new delete`

When I browse to, for example, `http://localhost:3000/sections/edit/4` I don't see the **prepopulated** values (the values from the DB which I wish to edit) in the webform.
I need to add some details. The edit and update methods (found in `sections_controller.rb`) are created as:

```
def edit
     @sect = Section.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @sect = Section.find(params[:id])
    if @sect.update_attributes(sect_params)
        redirect_to(:action=>'index')
    else
      render('edit') 
    end
  end
```

The `update` method doesn't require a template file, but `edit` does. So in the `view\sections\edit.html.erb` we have:

```
<%= form_for(:section, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @section.id}) do |f| %>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Field 1 </th>
        <td> <%= f.text_field(:field1) %> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Field 2 </th>
        <td> <%= f.text_field(:field2) %> </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<%= submit_tag("Edit section") %>
<% end %>
```

So the edit mechanism works perfectly, **except** that I don't see the prepopulated fields in the edit webform (which is inconvenient to say the least, especially in case of a large number of fields).
I already corrected this by renaming the `@sect` (only from method edit) instance variable to `@section`. However, I am puzzled and astounded by this solution. Shouldn't I supposedly **be allowed to choose any variable name**? Is this a Rails bug? Please enlighten me.

(In every other language I was free to choose any variable name as pleased without any repercussions.)

Comment: Yes, you could use any variable name, but should pass it to your form like `form_for @sect do |f|`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [at the docs for form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for).  You aren't giving it the model object it should be creating the form with, you're just basically specifying the object's name with the `:section` symbol.

Instead, pass the object you want to edit in (`form_for(@section...)`), that should get you the pre-populated fields you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nick! I switched back to using @sect (instead of @section) everywhere and did the change you indicated in the form_for:
`<%= form_for(@sect, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @sect.id}) do |f| %>` (so I replaced :section with @sect) - now I see the prepopulated fields , but when I click the "edit section" button I get: `No route matches [PATCH] "/sections/update/4" `, any idea why?

Could it be due to the fact I added a blank controller earlier (unrelated)? In routes.rb I have `match :controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]` as default route

Comment: Editing an existing object is typically though of as a `PATCH` or `PUT` operation, so you'll need to add that to your routes.  You may want to [try using resource-based routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) instead of specifying all of that stuff.